# Numerical simulations of standard model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, computational-physics, simulations, lattice-gauge-theory

Is standard model simulation a current and possible branch of research, or is it just lattice QCD?

Comment: sure monte carlo for comparing theory with data. example https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.05965 . the top quark involves weak interactions.  electromagnetic ones are always there in monte carlo simulations.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with trying to simulate the entire standard model in a lattice-discretisation, which I list below

- The large hierarchy of scales (i.e. up quarks/down quarks are at the MeV mass, while the electroweak scale is ~100 GeV) means that simulations would be very expensive to perform without very large systematic errors. Even for lattice-QCD calculations, modern calculations only simulate the up,down,strange (and sometimes charm) quarks, bottom and top quarks cannot be included without large errors.¹
- In principle, the QED landau pole presents a problem for trying to take a continuum limit of the standard model on the lattice. When people in practice simulate QCD+QED on the lattice, what they are really doing is probing the *perturbative* QED physics (and the continuum limit taken is never sensitive to the landau pole).
- There are problems with placing chiral fermions on the lattice ([Nielsen-Ninomiya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen%E2%80%93Ninomiya_theorem) theorem). There are various papers/proposals in recent years talking about this problem, I am not an expert but I am not super convinced it's possible to simulate the electroweak sector on the lattice (as the left/right degrees of freedom are different)

In practice, simulating the standard model in this way is not really necessary, as the electroweak sector is described very well by perturbation theory.

---

¹To be more precise, the u,d,s,c are simulated in the "sea" (which means loops including these quarks are included in the simulation). Relativistic valence bottom quarks are possible, but bottoms/tops are usually not included in the sea.